# Como acessar um container dentro de outro container em Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo uma função para modificar esses grupos de botões, porém não sei como acessar containers dentro de containers com Jquery.

```
<div class="buttons">
  <button aria-label="Right">Right</button>
  <button aria-label="Left">Left</button>
  <button aria-label="Center">Center</button>
  <button aria-label="Expand">Expand</button>
</div>
```

Consigo acessar esse container com `$(selector)`, porém quero no caso excluir o botão com o `aria-label="Expand"`. Pensei intuitivamente em 
`$(selector)[0].$("[aria-label=\"Expanded\"]").remove()`, porém deu erro de sintaxe. Como faço para acessar um container dentro de outro container em Jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente utilizar da seguinte forma:

```
$('.buttons').find('[aria-label="Expand"]').remove();
```

Estamos selecionando todos os filhos da div que contém a classe `buttons` com o seletor `$('.buttons')`. Após isso, pedimos para encontrar o elemento que contenha o atributo `aria-label="Expand"`, depois de encontra-lo basta remover com a função `remove()`.

Answer (score 1):

É bem simples, utilize a estrutura do css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#resultado").text($('.buttons button[aria-label="Expand"]').attr("aria-label"));
//oque você quer
$('.buttons button[aria-label="Expand"]').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <button aria-label="Right">Right</button>
  <button aria-label="Left">Left</button>
  <button aria-label="Center">Center</button>
  <button aria-label="Expand">Expand</button>
</div>
<span id="resultado"></span>
```